# Excel Bug: Why some cells in a time interval cells cannot be compared with accuracy?

Tags: excel, date, autofill, floating-accuracy, worksheet

When one drag a fill handle to fill times in a interval, some
cells with times cannot be compared in trustable way.

The bug reproduction is simple

a) Format Column `A` as Hour type (like hh:mm:ss)
b) Put `16:00`  in `A1`  e `16:10` in `A2`.
c) Drag the fill handle in the bottom right just 1 cell down
d) In `A3` shows `16:20`.
e) Put `16:20` in `B3`.
f) Put the formula `=A3=B3` in `C3`.
g) it shows `false`.

I know that internally Excel uses floating point for summing. For me, specially with times, it should add and round to seconds!

I use this kind of table to make statistics in a table database called [DB], where I use a criteria in order to sum a column [Occurrences]  in a 10 minutes time lapse based on a column [Dt].

There are 2 solutions, supposing that table starts in line 2

**a)**

Add 2 more columns `A` and `B`, with hour and minute both with formula, suppose that starts in line 2
`A2` and `B2` without formulas, with initial hour and minute.

**A3 (Hour)**: `=A2+IF(B2=50,1,0`)  ' Add 10 minutes to previous hour and minute
**B3 (Minutes)**:  `=B2 + IF(B2=50 ,0, B2+10)`
**C2 (Initial time)**:  `=Time(A2,B2,0)`  -> name `HI`
**D2 (Final time)**:  `=Time(A2,B2+10,0)` -> name `HF`

After, one can use C and D columns to build the criterion.

**E2 (Criterion)**: `=AND(Dt >= @HI, Dt <=@HF)`
**F2 (Query)**: `=DSUM(DB,"Occurrences",E1:E2)`

It sums occurrences between a 10 minutes lapse of time.

**b)**

I can also use a nerd solution for the criterion (it's my real solution that I've adopted, it's more concise), but it's awful.

Using directly C (name `HI`) and D (name `HF`) for time ranges:

**D2 (Criterion)**:

```
=AND(Hora>=MROUND(@HI,sec),Hora<MROUND(@HF,sec))
```

Where `sec` can be a named constant, that stores 1 second.
Press Ctrl+F3, New Name, `Name`: sec, `Value`: 0:0:1
(Thanks [Scott Cramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner))

**E2 (Query)**:

```
 =DSUM(DB,"Occurrences",D1:D2)
```

Sum field `occurrences` between a 10 minutes lapse of time.

**UPDATE**

Someone in the Microsoft Oficial Forum gave me a nice solution!

Just uses `=Time(16,Sequence(20,1,0,10),0)` in Office 365 and it generates a vertical strip from 20 times adding 10 minutes each step in a exact way starting from 16:00:00.

Comment: you can always use MROUND to force the rounding to seconds:  `=MROUND(A3,TIME(0,0,1))=MROUND(B3,TIME(0,0,1))`

Comment: @BigBen, I know that is a floating pont difference, but is not fair for dates. Excel should round it automacally in a fill operation.

Comment: Excel does not have a *date* type. They're numbers. No, this is not a bug. It is on the end-user to determine the precision needed (minutes, seconds, milliseconds, etc). If you disagree, raise an issue with MSFT.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it is a internal Excel feature, but the final user cannot be penalized., Final user uses the type date, including in VBA (`Dim Dt as Date`). The solution it would be Excel to use round after sum in fill process with 5  positions. It will solve completely the question.

Comment: But Excel allows 3 second decimals: `hh:mm:ss.000` how can Excel know to what precision one wants and another does.

Comment: The big mistake from Excel since the very beginnig are the choices. It would be much smarter to use seconds since data X (like many other languages) and not days. All time operations with any value in seconds it would be precise.

Comment: I will test MROUND, but I already solve with ROUND. I'll see if I can get smaller formulas than my nerd solution.

Comment: When Excel was built there were already products out there like it, they had to make theirs compatible.  All major spreadsheets followed this model, it was not Microsoft's choice it was made for them by the predecessor.

Comment: @ScottCraner, yes, you are right, Excel was married with its initial choices.

Comment: @BigBen, No need to be aggressive. I'm just looking to learn.

Comment: I spent almost 1 hour with Excel support via chat and the person was surprised by the error, as it is automatic filling of dates that cannot be tested. I even shared screens with the person until he reproduces my error. And he recommended me to go to the forums.

Comment: @ScottCraner, interesting that the `marred` works beautifully, but the `round` with
5 decimals doesn't work

Comment: @ScottCraner, your solution it would be much simpler than mine. I've learned a little bit more....